# PHP - The system cannot find the path specified. (but it finds it from another file)

Tags: php, filesystems, directory, directory-structure

My main app is at:

```
'.app/index.php'
```

What I do from there is parse a directory

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('./app/uploads/images/') as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
    $images[] = $fileInfo->getFilename();
}
```

And it works ok.

But, when I do the exact same thing from

```
'./app/models/tricky.php'
```

I get the error from the title.

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

I also tried modifying path to `'../app/uploads/images/'`
but have no clue what else to do.

Thanks.

Comment: Changing it to `../app/uploads/images` makes the directory `./app/app/uploads/images`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference and simple problem is:

You're two scripts are **not in the same directory**. If you use the './directory' notation, the '.' means starting at your current directory which is one time 'app' and the other time 'app/models/'.

Solve the problem by changing the path string in 'app/models/tricky.php' to **'../uploads/images/'**. The double dot '..' is important, it stands for the parent directory (go one directory up).

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem, and also +1 for clear explanation, it is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you have your routing set up, does:

```
'./app/index.php/models/tricky.php'
```

produce a result?

Also, you might implement:

is_dir('app/models/');

and see what you get (it'll produce a boolean value.

Let me know the results and perhaps that'll lead us somewhere helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. is_dir returned false, and modifying the path as above also didn't give results. What could be the next step?

Comment: Another answer solved it for me, but thanks for help and also for teaching me new function I didn't know about.

Comment: @Freelancer - yes. I use it quite a lot. It's a nice way to be able to test a handful of paths at once, without having to constantly reload, etc. Glad you solved it. Bests,